# iOS4 UIImagePickerController doesn't suport mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie]?

Tags: ios, ios4, mobilecoreservices

In my application,I want to open the camera in Video mode.So I write the following codes

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIImagePickerController *ipc;
    ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    ipc.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie];

    [viewController presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

This code is good for iPhone 3.1.3 but, on iOS4 does not work.
Can I use UIImagePickerController as a Video on iOS4?

Comment: I tried this source again today.
then no problem on this code.
I don't know why, but anyway forget about this.

Comment: in my case I getting error  `error: 'kUTTypeMovie' undeclared (first use in this function)` . . .any idea

Comment: @Amit Battan: you need to import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h> and add the MobileCoreServices framework to your project

Comment: @user102008 it is Ok .. please check my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514235/

Answer (score 3):

I'm new on iphone develop but i had the same problem and I solved that problem setting the mediaTypes like this

```
NSArray* mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]
ipc.mediaTypes = mediaTypes;
```

This allow you to have acces to the video and photo, i hope this help you