# UIImagePickerController mediatype kUTTypeMovie runtime exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am developing an iPhone App where I need to only view all the videos present in the Photos Library of a device. I am using the following code

```
UIImagePickerController picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];
```

I have imported  and added the MobileCoreServices framework to my project.

It works great on the iPhone 3GS, running on iOS 4.3, but when I run it on my iPod Touch, having iOS 4.2.1, it shows a runtime exception

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No available types for source 2'
```

I have tried replacing the term kUTTypeMovie with the string.

```
picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.movie"];
```

Again, it works great on the iPhone 3GS with the aforesaid iOS version, but again crashes on the iPod Touch.

I realized that UICoreTypes.h, which defines the above said string constant, is supported in devices with iOS 3 and above.

what could be the possible problem? I have followed other posts related to such problems, like [kUTTypeMovie not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093216/ios4-uiimagepickercontroller-doesnt-suport-mediatypes-nsarray-arraywithobjec)

but, this only tells us to include the above included framework. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the source type of the `UIImagePickerController`, have you set it to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`? It seems that you havent and therefore you get the no source available error, is the ipod touch you using have a video camera probably doesnt...

Comment: Thanks, I got the cause of the problem :)